# Next.js how to ignore a complete folder in app?

Tags: javascript, next.js, static-site-generation

On next 13, app/api folder creates an error during build when nextConfig.output is "export".

In my project, I need different build type depending on environnement variable.

Any way to ignore "api" folder during build when "output" is "export" ?

When I run build with nextConfig.output as "export" I got following error:

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
> /api/revalidate/route: /api/revalidate

#### src/app/api/revalidate/route.ts file

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { revalidateTag } from 'next/cache';
 
export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const tag = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get('tag');
  if(tag){
    revalidateTag(tag);
  }
  return NextResponse.json({ revalidated: true, now: Date.now() });
}
```

#### Next.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: process.env.NEXT_OUTPUT_MODE,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

### Reproducible repository

Here is a repository to reproduce this error
https://github.com/zeckaissue/next-export-api-crash

Comment: Can you show /api/revalidate/route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround with [ignore-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-loader). But maybe there is a better way to achieve my goal with a built-in feature of next.js

Here is my updated next.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: process.env.NEXT_OUTPUT_MODE,
  /**
   *
   * @param {import('webpack').Configuration} config
   * @param {import('next/dist/server/config-shared').WebpackConfigContext} context
   * @returns {import('webpack').Configuration}
   */
  webpack: (config) => {
    if (process.env.NEXT_OUTPUT_MODE !== "export" || !config.module) {
      return config;
    }
    config.module.rules?.push({
      test: /src\/app\/api/,
      loader: "ignore-loader",
    });
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: At the moment this seems to be the best solution available

Comment: @Zecka, when you do npm run build so the folder is not included right? are you getting this error when u try to access it

Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).

Comment: I have added this but my 'npm run build' still fails. I want to ignore everytg=hing under the 'externals' folder which is located in the root folder of the project.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = { 
  output: 'standalone',
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /.*externals.*/, // also tried /externals\/.*/ and /externals/
      loader: "ignore-loader",
    });

    return config;
  },
};
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

```
Failed to compile.

./externals/helpers.ts:59:29
```

Comment: @tot Send a reproducible github repo if you want some help

Comment: Problem solved. My problem was not web-pack but the TS compiler. Adding an exclude into the tsconfig.json fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work in NextJS 14...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ignore option in the Next.js configuration file (next.config.js).
You will have to create one config file if you havent already.
Open the next.config.js file and add the following code:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /YOUR FOLDER NAME\/.*/,
        loader: 'ignore-loader',
      });
}
```

Comment: this is basically the same solution than mine. Not sure why did you add "isServer" condition ?

Comment: The isServer option is added in the webpack configuration to differentiate between server-side and client-side builds in Next.js.
Thought this may help you !